# Hardware menu button not opening in Samsung galaxy tab 3

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-hardware

I have a samsung galaxy tab3 and I have the menu implemented in the usual manner - i.e.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and for menu selected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In my xml ive used  `android:showAsAction="never"` for items that I want to see in overflow and  `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for items I want to see upfront. But in this tablet I see only the ones with ifRoom set and the others just disappear and the menu button does not show the overflow items. I've looked at all answers on SO and tried the popular ones like setting `minimum and target sdk versions to less than 11` and so on. But the menu just wont come up. It works fine in devices that dont have the capacitive menu touch and an overflow button is shown in the action bar.

Comment: I'd start by changing `return true` to `return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu))`. Beyond that, try some sample code that is known to work. If that code does work on your device, determine where you are doing things differently. If the code fails on your device, there is something fluky with your device.

Comment: Well from another answer I tried overriding onKeyUp and explicitly catching the KEYCODE_MENU event, which also didnt work unfortunately. So maybe a case of fluky, darn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it ended up working when I programmatically called `openOptionsMenu` with `onKeyDown`

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

MAybe you have a theme (like full screen) that does not support an ActionBar?

Comment: Actually I do have the buttons on an action bar