# onCreateOptionsMenu on Samsung Galaxy Tablet 3 (GT-P5200)

Tags: android

as this is my first question on stackoverflow I am a bit nervous and hope I did not do anything wrong (at least I used the search function).

I have a problem during development an android app with following code (simplified) :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem test1 = menu.add(0, 1, 0, "test1");
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(test1, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    MenuItem test2 = menu.add(0, 2, 0, "test2");
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(test2, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    MenuItem test3 = menu.add(0, 3, 0, "test3");
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(test3, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    MenuItem test4 = menu.add(0, 4, 0, "test4");
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(test4, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    MenuItem test5 = menu.add(0, 5, 0, "test5");
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(test5, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case 3:
            Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case 4:
            Toast.makeText(this, "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case 5:
            Toast.makeText(this, "5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


}
```

This works as expected on all my test devices amongst others Android 2.6.3, 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 4.4, 5.0

Only one device make problems:

- **Galaxy Tab 3 (10.1)

  GT-P5200 / Android 4.2.2**

If I press the hardware menu button, no option menu is opening. Nothing happends.

I am using

- android studio
- support library version 21.0.3
- minSdkVersion 8
- targetSdkVersion 21

But strangely enough it works on other devices (e.g. Galaxy Note 8.0, GT-N5100, Android 4.2.2)

Can anybody test the code above on your devices?
Does anybody have a workaround?

**~~ EDIT: ~~**

I tried following code but the overflow menu does not open neither :-(

```
 Button btnOpenMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btnOpenMenu.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();

        }
    });
```

I think it must be a bug in the latest support library v7 version 21.0.x

But why only on the Samsung Galaxy Tablet 3 ??

Many thanks

-Gra

Comment: Setting the `targetVersion` to `11` is an often suggested workaround (see for instance http://lancelotmobile.com/blog/mobile-air-app-compatible-with-android-4/). What are the "other problems" you mentioned?

Comment: *Setting the targetVersion to 11...* then you will be not able to use ActionBarActivity(nor support library at all)

Comment: anyway, similar question has an answer here already ...

Comment: I found a similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326624/hardware-menu-button-not-opening-in-samsung-galaxy-tab-3 unfortunatelly the workaround is not working on my tablet. it seems to be a specific problem with the gt-p5200. Strange.